# Shiny app as package: css & all www/ directory stuff

Tags: css, r, shiny, package

I'm trying to convert a Shiny app into an R package and I am having trouble with all things regarding the www directory as well as "loose" files.

My shiny app works perfectly but when I try to "package it", it doesn't work.

My shiny app directory:

```
+---my_shiny
|   +---app.R
|   +---utils.R
|   +---www
|       +---style.css
|       +---icon1.png
|       +---icon2.png
|       +---icon3.png
|       +---font.ttf
```

My code starts like this:

```
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

source(here::here("utils.R"))

theme_set(theme_personalized())
update_geom_defaults("text", list(family = theme_get()$text$family))

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Example",
  id = "navbar",
  theme = "style.css",
```

Now I down't know how to convert it into a package where I can call myapp::appdemo() and it deploys my app.

```
+---myapp
|   +---DESCRIPTION
|   +---NAMESPACE  
|   +---R
|       +---appdemo.R
|   +---inst
|       +---shiny/
|           +---app.R
|           +---utils.R
|           +---style.css
|           +---icon1.png
|           +---icon2.png
|           +---icon3.png
|           +---font.ttf
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to make it to.

Comment: Have you had a look [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-packaging.html)? But I admit that this chapter is not very detailed. The only thing I see in your folder structure is that you use `inst/shiny` instead of `inst/www`. Maybe it helps if you change that?

Comment: Yes, I did! I think that chapter is not finished yet and hence de "inst/www?". I partially solved the problem by: (i) putting the app and utils on R/ and (ii) by publishing the images online and reading them from the url. The css part is not that simple (I tryied inserting the css on the app itself) :(

Comment: When you install the package, a folder in `inst` gets copied to the higher level, so `inst/www` should be correct (or did I miss a change that `www` is now called `shiny`?)

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reverse-engineered the approach used by the [{golem} framework](https://engineering-shiny.org/golem.html) to find a method which seems to work:

- Everything which you would normally put in `www` should now go in `inst/app/www`. In package development, the `inst` folder is used for arbitrary additional files that you want include in your package.
- Add `inst/app/www` as a 'resource path' as follows:

  ```
  resources <- system.file("app/www", package = "my-package-name")
  addResourcePath("www", resources)
  ```
- Use the following in your app's UI to embed the resources:

  ```
  tags$head(

    # Javascript resources
    htmltools::htmlDependency(
      name = "resources",
      version = "0.0.1",
      src = resources,
      script = list.files(resources, pattern = "\\.js$", recursive = TRUE),
      package = NULL,
      all_files = TRUE
    ),

    # CSS resources
    lapply(
      list.files(resources, pattern = "\\.css$", recursive = TRUE),
      function(x) tags$link(href = file.path("www", x), rel = "stylesheet")
    )

  )
  ```

### EDIT

I've been testing this on a package and the above no longer seems to work when the package is installed (although it works with `devtools::load_all()`).

To fix, you need to add resources in the package's call to `.onLoad()`, which should typically live in `R/zzz.R`:

```r
# R/zzz.R

.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    resources <- system.file("app/www", package = "my-package-name")
    addResourcePath("www", resources)
}
```