# Shiny app as function, where to put www/ folder, CSS, JS

Tags: css, r, shiny, htmltools

I am attempting to convert a relatively complex shiny app (3-4 modules, 8 CSS/JS files) into a package with one external function that builds an instance of an app for a given input (`build_myApp(dataset1, title, factors)` which is stored in `build_myApp.R` within the `R/` directory, along with `myApp_server.R`, `myApp_ui.R` and various helper files).

I have been following this example [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/function.html) and it all works well now except the styling has disappeared. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360170/shiny-app-as-package-css-all-www-directory-stuff), someone appears to have similar issues, however without trying to "*functionize*" their app.

Previously, I have put external files in a top-level `www` folder, and called them from the top-level `ui.R` file like this: `tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "sample1.css")` or `tags$script(src="www/sample.js")`. However I am currently unable to access any of them, and am possibly unable to access other external css, though hard to tell for sure.

I have tried leaving the `www` header at top-level, putting it within an `inst/` top-level folder, and moving it within `R/` and restarted R session & rebuilt package each time. For completionists-sake, in all of those I have tried permutations of:

- `sample1.css`
- `./sample2.css`
- `../sample3.css`
- `www/sample4.css`
- `./www/sample5.css`
- `../www/sample6.css`
- `/www/sample7.css`
- `inst/www/sample8.css`
- `/inst/www/sample9.css`
- `./inst/www/sample10.css`
- `../inst/www/sample11.css`
- `inst/sample12.css`
- `/inst/sample13.css`
- `./inst/sample14.css`
- `../inst/sample15.css`

Unfortunately the [Mastering Shiny Chapter](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-packaging.html) doesn't mention it and I can't find any other references online. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this issue or it is still an open question - what works for me is putting the .css file in the inst/ folder of the package and then accessing it in the UI with system.file, i.e.

```
includeCSS(system.file("myCSSfile.css", package = "myPackageName"))
```